# Load variables from text file

Tags: file, powershell, text

The script below asks for the `$tag1` variable and uses that, but instead of entering in 1 variable at a time, I want to load a text file with many variables. I know you can use `Get-Content c:\scripts\test.txt | Foreach-Object` but I am not sure how to use it in this situation.

```
Get-Content C:\Users\ajstepanik\Desktop\tags.txt | Foreach-Object { write-host $_

    #Windows XP 
    $reg  = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $tag1)
    $key  = $reg.OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon')
    $winxp = $key.GetValue('DefaultUserName') -replace '^.*?\\'

    #Windows 7
    $reg1  = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $tag1)
    $key1  = $reg1.OpenSubKey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI')
    $win7 = $key1.GetValue('LastLoggedOnUser') -replace '^.*?\\'

    set-alias psloggedon 'C:\Users\ajstepanik\Desktop\PSTools\PsLoggedon.exe'




    echo "Windows XP"
    echo "----------"
    echo $winxp

    "`n"

    echo "Windows 7"
    echo "----------"
    echo $win7

    "`n"

    $pstools = psloggedon \\$tag1
    echo $pstools

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything and gotten stuck somewhere? What variables do you want to load, a list of IP Addresses and what not, then loop through those?

Comment: I figured if I added >> outputfile.txt to the end of every output it would work, but how do I tell the script to accept input from a file?

Comment: You look like you are close: try `get-content File.txt | foreach-object { write-host $_ }` to see what happens and go from there

Comment: @AustinFrench I did what you said and updated my OP. It did not work, I guess I am trying to tell it to use the variables in the text file in place of where the $tag1 variable is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to attempt to rewrite your script for you, but you need to do something like this:

```
$fileinput = Get-Content c:\tags.txt

foreach ($tag in $fileinput)
{
  Write-Host $tag
  # Or whatever it is you're trying to do here
}
```